# Rails validations or possibly routing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, error-handling, routes

I'm having trouble in a forum I'm making.

I put a validates :content, presence: true into my comment model and now I'm getting a cascade of errors.

The one I'm stuck at now is:
[image]

It only happens when a user comments on their OWN post without putting in any content. If they break the validation in another users post then an error message gets rendered correctly.

Why would a comment validation cause a crash related to edit post path?? The two shouldn't be related.

Here is the page where the crash happens.

```html
<div class="conversations-content-items forum-bg">
  <div class="post-main-container post-show-border">
    <div class="post-group">
      <div class="post-header">
        <div class="post-creation-time">
          <p>Posted by: <%= @post.user.username %> at <%= @post.created_at.strftime("%l:%M %p") %></p>
        </div>
        <% if @post.user == current_user %>
          <%= link_to edit_post_path do %>
            <i class="fas fa-edit icon-shrink"></i>
          <% end %> <!-- link to edit -->
        <% end %> <!-- if @user -->
      </div>
      <div class="post-title">
        <p><%= @post.title %></p>
      </div>
      <div class="post-content">
        <p><%= @post.content %></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="post-toolbar">
      <span class="post-comment-icon">
        <img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-two-tone/24/000000/topic.png"/>
      </span>
      <span class="number-of-comments">
        <%= @post.comments.size %> <p class='ml-1'>Comments</p>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="comments-container">
    <%= render 'comments/comment_form', post: @post, comment: @comment %>
    <div class="comments-display">
      <% @post.comments.each do |parent_comment| %>
        <%= render 'comments/comment', post: @post, comment: parent_comment, parent_comment: parent_comment %>
        <div class="comment-replies">
          <% parent_comment.replies.each do |reply| %>
            <%= render 'comments/comment', post: @post, comment: reply, parent_comment: parent_comment %>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the comments controller

```html
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @comment = Comment.new
    authorize @comment
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @language = @post.language
    @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
    @comment.user = current_user
    @comment.post = @post
    new_cp_total = current_user.convo_points + 2
    current_user.update(convo_points: new_cp_total)
    authorize @comment
    if @comment.save
      redirect_to post_path @post
    else
      render "posts/show", layout: "conversations"
    end
  end

  def show
    @comment = @post.comment
    authorize @comment
  end

  private

  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:content, :post_id, :user_id, :comment_id)
  end
end
```

Heres where the comment gets submitted

```html
<div class="comment-form-hub">
  <%= render 'devise/shared/error_messages', resource: comment %>
  <%= form_for [post, comment] do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field(:comment_id, value: parent_comment&.id, hidden: true) if defined?(parent_comment) %>
    <div class="post-create-comment">
      <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Share your thoughts...", class: "comment-form" %>
    </div>
    <div class="post-comment-submit-wrapper">
      <%= f.submit "Comment", class: "comment-button border-glow" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

and here are the routes

```html
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root to: 'pages#home'

  mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', as: 'rails_admin'
  post 'messages', to: 'messages#create'

  devise_for :users, controllers: {
    sessions: 'users/sessions',
    registrations: 'users/registrations'
  }

  authenticate :user, ->(user) { user.admin? } do
    mount Blazer::Engine, at: "blazer"
  end

  resources :languages, only: :index, path: "/", param: :lang do
    member do
      resources :posts, only: :index, path: 'forum', as: :forum
      resources :posts, only: :new
      resources :messages, only: :index, path: 'chat', as: :chat
    end
  end

  get '/leaderboards', controller: 'pages', action: 'leaderboards'

  post '/contact/send', controller: 'contact', action: 'send_message'

  resources :posts, only: [ :create, :show, :edit, :update ] do
    resources :comments, only: [:create, :destroy]
  end

  resources :messages, only: :create

  resources :users, only: :show

  resources :games, only: [ :show, :index ] do
    resources :plays, only: :create
  end

  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **edit_post_path** url helper must receive at least the ID of the post that you want to edit, otherwise the helper can't infer how to generate the url.

Try this instead:

```
<%= link_to edit_post_path(@post.id) do %>
```

A little bit more of an explanation:

Any url helper of this kind of REST resource must have an **ID**entificator for generating the URL, so:

**edit_post_path(36)** will generate the url:

```
/posts/36/edit
```

**edit_comment_path(8)** will generate the url:

```
/comments/8/edit
```

without the ID the url helper can't build the proper route:

```
/comments/???/edit  # would raise an error because there are no route configured for this
```

note that this resources dont need to be necessarily correlated, but in wherever view/page (.html.erb) you render a url via a url helper (for *link_to*, *form_with*, *redirect_to*, etc...), the route must be well formed.

Comment: That fixed it, thanks! I still don't understand why though because the comment button shouldn't be connected to the edit post button....

Comment: I edited my answer, trying to add a little bit more of context for you